# How to use nested AWS CLI command syntax?

Tags: bash, aws-cli

Below are the two different AWS CLI commands, running on bash:

```
IMAGES_TO_DELETE=$( aws ecr list-images --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json )

aws ecr batch-delete-image --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-ids "$IMAGES_TO_DELETE" || true
```

where first command stores JSON format `[ {"imageDigest": "sha256:..."}, {"imageDigest": "sha256:..."}, ... ]` in `IMAGES_TO_DELETE`

---

In a scenario, where I can run single nested command:

```
aws ecr batch-delete-image --region us-west-2 --repository-name "somedockerimage" --image-ids “$(aws ecr list-images --region us-west-2 --repository-name "somedockerimage" --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output text)” || true
```

gives error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--image-ids': Expected: '=', received: '“' for input:
“sha256:cccccccccc983f4185f48fb968634dae8c4276ee1a7ffffffffffffff
^
```

---

```
aws ecr batch-delete-image --region us-west-2 --repository-name "somedockerimage" --image-ids “$(aws ecr list-images --region us-west-2 --repository-name "somedockerimage" --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json)” || true
```

gives error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--image-ids': Expected: '=', received: '“' for input:
“[
^
```

---

What is the nested syntax to replace `"$IMAGES_TO_DELETE"` in the second command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the smart quotes `“...”` to straight quotes `"..."`.